# How would I modify a <div> element to both center on webpage & maintain its size attributes?

Tags: html, css

"How To"
How do I modify a "div" to cause a single element to be centered on the webpage (maintaining its current size attributes)?

See this page: https://abacuscustompainting.com

Notice the "Residential Services" Page Section, then specifically the "Interior Painting" element. 
Notice how it remains left-aligned, rather than centered (as I wish it to be) underneath the "Residential Services" header.

Also note this element was once one of multiple elements within a div table. I've successfully modified the original code to remove the other unwanted elements - but, alas, I'm left with a left-aligned attribute for this element.

I cannot identify whether the element is left-aligned by way of a direct attribute forcing that behavior, or if it's left-aligned behavior, is the result of a wrapping attribute I've not identified.

Your educated "code corrections" and a layman's explanation would be of great value to me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree, it's partially that class, `.fusion-layout-column`:

```
    .fusion-layout-column.fusion-one-fourth {
width: 25%;}
```

So that's telling it to be a 1/4 column.

Then there's also `.fusion-layout-column`, telling it to float left.

Then you also need to add `text-align:center` to the content in that row or that column -

```
  .fusion-column-wrapper.fusion-column-wrapper-8 {[enter image description here][1]
text-align: center;}
```

worked well when I tried it in Dev Tools, or add your own class to that column, like "go-center-darnit" and add into you stylesheet

```
.go-center-darnit {
text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't let me attach the image because i'm "new". Here's a link to my Dev Tools screen shot - https://snipboard.io/j7ANs2.jpg

Answer (score -1):

The left-aligned behavior is caused by the class ".fusion-layout-column" given to the "Interior Painting" parent div, you can include an inline css to override the float:left behavior and add a margin: auto to center the div.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way you could do it would be to apply a `flex-box` style to the parent container.

[image: The resultant layout]

```
<div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-builder-row-inner fusion-row " style="display:flex;align-items:center;align-content:center;justify-content:center;width:100%;">

    <div class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_4  fusion-one-fourth fusion-column-second 2_4" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 30px;width:25%;width:calc(25% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.25 ) );margin-right:4%;">
        <div class="fusion-column-wrapper fusion-column-wrapper-8" style="padding: 0px; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; height: auto;" data-bg-url="">
            <span class="fusion-imageframe imageframe-none imageframe-7 hover-type-none">
                <a class="fusion-no-lightbox" href="interior-painting/index.html" target="_self" aria-label="interior painting">
                    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/12/interior-painting-2.jpg" width="455" height="300" alt="Interior Painting" class="img-responsive wp-image-11052" srcset="wp-content/uploads/2015/12/interior-painting-2-200x132.jpg 200w, wp-content/uploads/2015/12/interior-painting-2-400x264.jpg 400w, wp-content/uploads/2015/12/interior-painting-2.jpg 455w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 455px">
                </a>
            </span>
            <div class="fusion-sep-clear"></div>
            <div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep sep-none" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"></div>
            <div class="fusion-text">
                <p>High end quality <a>interior painting services</a> at affordable rates… <a><strong>Learn More</strong></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The styles, applied inline here in the console, are

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
align-content:center;
justify-content:center;
width:100%;
```